# Date and time in two columns respectively. How to obtain difference in hours?

Tags: excel

I have a large spreadsheet in which a start date is captured in cell D10 and a start time in E10. The end date is captured in J10 and end time in K10. In column y I need the difference in hours such that I may total column y to give me the total in hours that the generator was utilised in a month.

I have tried concatenating then using a formula like :-
=TEXT(x10-w10, "d:h:mm")

Comment: Why are you using W10 and Y10 in your formula when the information is in cells D10, E10, J10 and K10?

Comment: @Jerry I concatenated D10&E10 in W10 and J10&K10  in x10 then used the formula =TEXT(x10-w10,"d:h:mm")

Comment: If you store dates and times as actual dates, `(j10 + k10) - (d10 + e10)`. The result is also a date to which you would apply the `[h]:mm` format to make sure `h` can go beyond 24. If you store them as something else, store them as dates instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=(J10+K10-D10-E10)*24
```

Then change format to number.

In Excel, a day difference is equal to 1, therefore an hour difference is equal to 1/24.